# Enums with some properties in protobuf

Tags: java, enums, protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-java

In java, we can define enums with some properties inside it like -

```
public enum Enum1{
    A1(true, 1, "A1"),
    B1(false,2,"B1");
    private boolean isTrue;
    private int index;
    private String name;
    public Enum1(boolean isTrue, int index, String name){
       this.isTrue = isTrue;
       this.index = index;
       this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I want to migrate this model to protobuf message format.
I can see protobufs provide options to create enums. But how do I create enums who are having multiple properties like it's supported in Java?

Comment: You can't. In java, enum constants are a predefined list of instances of that enum class. That means that you can provide an enum class with fields and methods. But in most other language, an enum is nothing else but named constants for numeric values, hence the name enumeration.